# What's the next step after #import when using Scripting.FileSystemObject in C++?

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2010, filesystemobject, xlw

Context: Windows 7, XLW 5.x, Microsoft Excel 2007, Visual Studio 2010, C++

Given the following bit of code ...

```
#import "c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll" raw_interfaces_only, \
raw_native_types, \
named_guids, \
rename("DeleteFile", "_DeleteFile"), \
rename("MoveFile","_MoveFile"), \
rename("CopyFile", "_CopyFile"), \
rename("GetFreeSpace", "_GetFreeSpace")
using namespace Scripting;
```

How do I now instantiate the FileSystemObject and call its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
std::wstring fileExists(std::wstring name)
{
    VARIANT_BOOL b = 0;
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        CComPtr<IFileSystem> spFSO;
        HRESULT hr = spFSO.CoCreateInstance(L"Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spFSO)
        {
            BSTR theName = SysAllocStringLen( name.data(), name.size());
            hr = spFSO->FileExists(theName, &b);
        }
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return (b == -1) ? L"Exists" : L"Doesn't exist";
}
```

That at least got me connected to the functionality. There's still the getting it right for the situation, but that's beyond the scope of the posting.